# CEF sharp 3 retriving response headers

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

So Im still trying to find the feature (if it is there) in Cefsharp 3, where one can inspect the headers from the response of a request. In case its not there, is it because it is not there in CEF 3 ?  and or, where should i start looking, if Im to implement it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is not in CEF 3 yet.  Here's the outstanding issue for it:
https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=515

There is a workaround noted...

> There's no great way to filter response contents with CEF3 currently. You can use CefResourceHandler via CefRequestHandler::GetResourceHandler and execute the request/return the response contents yourself using CefURLRequest.

... however this workaround is not possible in CefSharp 3 because `CefURLRequestClient` and friends are not implemented.

At this stage, depending on how comfortable you are with C++ you might consider:

- contributing to the (C++) CEF project and implement the response filtering feature - this will be all C++.
- contributing C# wrappers of `CefURLRequestClient` and friends to the CefSharp project - which is a combination of light C++ and C#.

You might also be interested that there is a way to get HTTP headers in JavaScript, as long as you have initiated the request yourself using AJAX:
[Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

This type of solution could easily be done with CefSharp 3 by injecting JavaScript into the current page.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that provides more control is to use schemehandlers (it's cleaner IMO).

Add a scheme handler that intercepts your resource loading:

```
CEF.RegisterScheme("ascheme", new HandlerFactory());
```

then (once you've created a trivial factory or 2) you have this override available:

```
public bool ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest request, ISchemeHandlerResponse response, OnRequestCompletedHandler requestCompletedCallback)
```

The Response contains Headers/MimeType and Stream to allow more control. I hope this helps.

Comment: Using a scheme handler intercepts the loading prior to the request being sent, so there is no way to get the original response - you have to submit the request and return the response manually using .NET's `WebClient`/`WebRequest`, but this has drawbacks (cookies not being passed, different user-agent, etc.).

Comment: The request object in the above method allows access to the full request as well as the headers. I thought that's what the question asked.

Comment: He wants the headers from the response instead.